# Scala compilation issue when using Java library with interface using generic type

Tags: scala, generics, interface, compiler-errors

In a Scala project, I am using  Java livrary (bouncycastle).

I have a compilation issue when using a method that required an object implementing a generic type.

Here is the interface in Java:

```
public interface Selector<T> extends Cloneable
{
    boolean match(T obj);
    Object clone();
}
```

Here is the piece of code that does not compile:

```
def verify(data: File): Boolean = {
    val signedData = new CMSSignedData(new CMSProcessableFile(data), Base64.decode(this.value))
    val certStore = signedData.getCertificates
    val signers = signedData.getSignerInfos.getSigners
    val signer = signers.iterator.next
    val certs = certStore.getMatches(signer.getSID)
    val cert = certs.iterator.next.asInstanceOf[X509CertificateHolder]
    signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert))
}
```

When I compile the code, I get the following error:

```
[error]  found   : org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerId
[error]  required: org.bouncycastle.util.Selector[?0]
[error]     val certs = certStore.getMatches(signer.getSID)
```

I tried casting but I does not compile.

Coule you please help?

Regards,

Comment: What is the signature of `getMatches` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedData.html, `getCertificates` returns a raw `Store` object instead of `Store<Something>`. Scala doesn't support working with raw types, generally speaking (they only exist in Java to interoperate with pre-Java-5 code). It's documented as

> Return any X.509 certificate objects in this SignedData structure as a Store of X509CertificateHolder objects.

So you can try

```
val certStore = signedData.getCertificates.asInstanceOf[Store[X509CertificateHolder]]
```

and you'll also need casts in any other places where raw `Store` or `Selector` are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I modified:

```
def verify(data: File): Boolean = {
  val signedData = new CMSSignedData(new CMSProcessableFile(data), Base64.decode(this.value))
  val certStore = signedData.getCertificates.asInstanceOf[Store[X509CertificateHolder]]
  val signers = signedData.getSignerInfos.getSigners
  val signer = signers.iterator.next
  val certs = certStore.getMatches(signer.getSID.asInstanceOf[Selector[X509CertificateHolder]])
  val cert = certs.iterator.next
  signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert))
}
```

Now, the code compile without problem!

Thanks a lot.

Kind Regards,